# 405 Method Not Supported on HTTP Delete with .Net Core 3.0 WebApi

Tags: asp.net-core, http, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I've generated a WebAPI with .NetCore 3.0 but every time i try to make a HttpDelete it returns"405 Method not Supported".

After looking for a while i only found "Remove WebDave in webconfig" but the .NetCore 3.0 WebApi project does not have a WebConfig.

Edit2: The request is simply a Delete request on 'https://localhost:5001/api/ambiente/1', the Get on 'https://localhost:5001/api/ambiente' works perfectly

The controller was generated with the command `dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name AmbienteController -async -api -m Ambiente-dc CotacaoContext -outDir Controllers`

and a simplified(removed the other methods) Version of the controller is:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using CotacaoBackEnd.Data;
using CotacaoBackEnd.Models;

namespace CotacaoBackEnd.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AmbienteController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly CotacaoContext _context;

        public AmbienteController(CotacaoContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }


        // DELETE: api/Ambiente/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Ambiente>> DeleteAmbiente(int id)
        {
            var ambiente = await _context.Ambientes.FindAsync(id);
            if (ambiente == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Ambientes.Remove(ambiente);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return ambiente;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: is there a public action on the controller with `[HttpDelete]` attribute that matches the requested route? If not then that is the problem

Comment: Please share the relevant controller code.

Comment: WebDAV is irrelevant

Comment: Give an example of the request made. Can you include the relevant controller definition and its adorned attributes (ie Route, etc)

Answer (score 0):

For `[HttpDelete]` on action,if you call it using `GET` method, you will get a `405` error.You need to share us the way you test it. In Postman,`405` from

[image]

If you use `DELETE`, it will get `200`.

[image]